# Out of memory in view pager

Tags: android, android-memory

I have more than 15 images to show in view pager, I am getting `OutOfMemoryException` error

My adapter code goes like this

```
public class ViewPagerAdapterScreenshots extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
ArrayList<Integer> imageRes;

public ViewPagerAdapterScreenshots(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> images) {
    this.context = context;
    imageRes = images;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.screenshots, null);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.screenshot);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageRes.get(position));
    container.addView(v);
    return v;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imageRes.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0.equals(arg1);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);

}

}
```

and my activity code goes like this

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager screenshots;
CirclePageIndicator pi;
private ArrayList<Integer> imageRes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

private static int[] imageIds = { R.drawable.help1, R.drawable.help2, R.drawable.help3, R.drawable.help4, R.drawable.help5, R.drawable.help6, R.drawable.help7,
        R.drawable.help8, R.drawable.help9, R.drawable.help10, R.drawable.help11, R.drawable.help12, R.drawable.help13, R.drawable.help14, R.drawable.help15 };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setWindowLayout();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();

    screenshots.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapterScreenshots(this, imageRes));
    pi.setViewPager(screenshots);
    screenshots.setCurrentItem(getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0));

}
```

can any one suggest me how to over come this memoryleak.

Answer (score 0):

The `OutOfMemoryException` is likely being raised because you are running out of `Bitmap` memory. This means that you are trying to handle more images than the phone's `Bitmap` memory can handle. It is not necessarily a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Look for examples on baseAdpters and PagerAdapters, you got all mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "FragmentPagerAdapter" which is implementation of "PagerAdapter", each page is represented as Fragment.